# JsonPath checking for a value in message sent by AWS SNS

Tags: json, apache-camel, jsonpath

I am trying to do a check on the **notificationType** sent by an amazon notification. 
I want to check if this type is 'Delivery' so I can route it to a different location using camel.

My initial attempt was **$.Message[?(@notificationType = 'Delivery')]** but I got the error *can not be applied to a JSON object only a JSON array*

I have been trying various ways online http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator but I can not seem to extract that value or to do a check.

```
{
  "Type": "Notification",
  "MessageId": "defg",
  "TopicArn": "arn:email",
  "Message": "{\"notificationType\":\"Delivery\",\"mail\":{\"timestamp\":\"2014-11-10T12:46:52.599Z\",\"source\":\"example@example.com\",\"messageId\":\"000001499000000\",\"destination\":[\"example@example.com\"]},\"delivery\":{\"timestamp\":\"2014-11-10T12:46:53.949Z\",\"processingTimeMillis\":1350,\"recipients\":[\"example@example.com\"],\"smtpResponse\":\"250 2.0.0 OK 1415623613 u3si30734178qat.92 - gsmtp\",\"reportingMTA\":\"abc\"}}",
  "Timestamp": "2014-11-10T12:46:54.003Z",
  "SignatureVersion": "1",
  "Signature": "sXkzkMQGawqJCibQ==",
  "SigningCertURL": "https:xyz",
  "UnsubscribeURL": "https:zyx"
}
```

**Edit 1** I have just noticed that none of the online parses seem to be working. Even the examples don't work in them

Answer (score 1):

I thought SNS can put values in headers. 
If so you can route based upon matching attributes in the header.

Comment: I hope so because the reason you can't use JsonPath on the above json is that the Message is parsed strings so the JsonPath will never be able to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Message Json returned from Amazon is escaped Strings.

Jackson parses the above with the escaped strings find but but JsonPath will not.

If you changed the Json to below the command below works.

> $.Message[?(@.notificationType == 'Delivery')]

```
[
   {
      "notificationType" : "Delivery",
      "mail" : {
         "timestamp" : "2014-11-10T12: 46: 52.599Z",
         "source" : "example@example.com",
         "messageId" : "000001499000000",
         "destination" : [
            "example@example.com"
         ]
      },
      "delivery" : {
         "timestamp" : "2014-11-10T12: 46: 53.949Z",
         "processingTimeMillis" : 1350,
         "recipients" : [
            "example@example.com"
         ],
         "smtpResponse" : "2502.0.0OK1415623613u3si30734178qat.92-gsmtp",
         "reportingMTA" : "abc"
      }
   }
]
```